# Do you know how to solve this problem when building under holo? CS0234

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, hololens

I'm new to this and can't figure out how to fix these errors that keep me from building a project for HoloLens. I would be very happy if you could help me with this problem, I think that it is so easy because I have not found other information about it.

[image: Unity menu with errors]

Comment: As error message says, you have to add referenced assemblies to use specified namespaces

Comment: like Mateusz stated add the reference... you find info on that topic on the unity website or documentation. I also think i remember that the official microsoft hololens page got these dll's for download especially for unity.

Comment: Just another hint: You should follow the other warnings and switch to IL2CPP as scripting backend. And then your visual studio will need `C++ Universal Windows Platform tools` installed as was explained [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/selected-visual-studio-is-missing-required-components-and-may-not-be-able-to-build-the-generated.528478/)

Answer (score 0):

You should change Minimum Platform Version upto 10.0.10586.0. Your version isn't compatible with Windows Mixed Reality.